# Using python how do I repeatedly divide a number by 2 until it is less than 1.0?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am unsure of how to create the loop to keep dividing the number by two? Please help. I know you you can divide a number by 2 don't know how to create the loop to keep dividing until it is less than 1.0.

Comment: Please show what you've tried and what causes you problems.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what exactly you're after as it isn't clear from the question. A function that just divides a number by zero until it is less than 1.0 would look like this:

```
def dividingBy2(x):

    while x > 1.0:
        x = x/2
```

But this serves no purpose other than understanding while loops, as it gives you no information. If you wanted to see how many times you can divide by 2 before a number is less than 1.0, then you could always add a counter:

```
def dividingBy2Counter(x):

    count = 0

    while x > 1.0:
        x = x/2
        count = count + 1

    return count
```

Or if you wanted to see each number as x becomes increasingly small:

```
def dividingBy2Printer(x):

    while x > 1.0:
        x = x/2
        print(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
b=[]  #initiate a list to store the result of each division

#creating a recursive function replaces the while loop
#this enables the non-technical user to call the function easily

def recursive_func(a=0):  #recursive since it will call itself later

    if a>=1:  #specify the condition that will make the function run again
        a = a/2 #perform the desired calculation(s)
        recursive_func(a) #function calls itself
        b.append(a)    #records the result of each division in a list

#this is how the user calls the function as an example
recursive_func(1024)
print (b)
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer?

Comment: The function calls itself after each division while the condition is met (a>=1 in this case). Since the problem didn't specify what was needed, I wanted to add the result of each division to a list ( b ). We can add a counter to see the number of steps to reach one if needed.